# Cant show ProgressDialog from non UI thread. How to?

Tags: android, progressdialog

Trying to show ProgressDialog, but getting:
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare().

Here is my code:

```
    public class SocketThread implements Runnable {
    BufferedReader in;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public void run() 
    {
        socket = null;

        while (true)
        {
            // Loop until connected to server
            while (socket == null){
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
                dialog.setMessage("Connecting to " + gatewayString);
                dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                AdvancedMultipleSeriesGraph.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {     
                    public void run() {
                        dialog.show();

                    }
                });
```

Is it possible to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use an Handler and use `Handler.post(Runnable)` or, if you have an activity context you can use `Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable action)`

Comment: I didn't know the "Activity.runOnUiThread(...)" method. Great to be aware of it now.

Comment: Maybe I dont understand you, but my code is the same as you suggested:
AdvancedMultipleSeriesGraph.this.runOnUiThread(...)

Comment: could you try Handler mHandler = new Handler(); and instead of runOnUiThread mHandler.post(new Runnable()      
                    public void run() {
                        dialog.show();

                    }
                });

Comment: Or maybe it's because you don't create the ProgressDialog from the UI thread

Comment: I think the problem is    dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext()); try to instantiate dialog in the Activity context (in the oncreate for instance)

Comment: I tried to add to onCreate initiation: dialog = new ProgressDialog(getBaseContext());
  mHandler = new Handler();
and then the code from 4th comment and now getting:
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: Thanks for help! Solved by changing "new ProgressDialog(getBaseContext());" to "new ProgressDialog(this);"

Comment: @blackbelt I am in a Thread that was started by a service. I have tried to use a HandlerThread + Handler to post a runnable that shows the ProgressDialog. However, I get "Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application". I am calling .show(mContext,...) where I gave the service and then the thread the Activity that started the service as a context. I can do other things like show Toasts in this manner, so the context seems to be valid. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

**NEVER!!!** perform UI update from a thread different from the UI thread.

A solution could be to add a reference on the handler when you create the thread so that you could dispatch update notification in the UI thread.